# "setURLToShare" must be called for call-to-action to work

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, google-plus

Till yesterday I was able to execute following code to share on user's google+ profile but suddenly today it says in console log that `[GPPShareBuilderImpl getURL] |setURLToShare:| must be called for call-to-action to work`. 

**Code :**

```
[GPPShare sharedInstance].delegate = self;

id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] shareDialog];

// This line will manually fill out the title, description, and thumbnail of the
// item you're sharing.
[shareBuilder setTitle:@"AppName"
           description:@"App description."
          thumbnailURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.example.com/image.png"]];

/* This line passes the deepLinkID to our application
 if somebody opens the link on a supported mobile device */
[shareBuilder setContentDeepLinkID:@"post"];

// set the text of post. user can edit this before sharing.
[shareBuilder setPrefillText:@"I just created a trip from XYZ app."];

// This will create a call-to-action button with the specified label.
// - URL specifies where people will go if they click the button on a platform
// that doesn't support deep linking.
// - deepLinkID specifies the deep-link identifier that is passed to your native
// application on platforms that do support deep linking
[shareBuilder setCallToActionButtonWithLabel:@"Install"
                                         URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/"]
                                  deepLinkID:@"install"];

[shareBuilder open];
```

According to [Google+ documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share)(`Share without URL` section) I can use below method instead of `setURLToShare:`. And this method was working fine till yesterday.

```
[shareBuilder setTitle:@"title"
                 description:@"description";
                thumbnailURL:@"url"];
```

I have not found anything on Google+ related to this. I tried deleting the app and installing again. Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing without URL works only for basic sharing, if you want to use interactive posts you need to call setURLToShare. You can find a note in the header GPPShare.h:

```
// Note: In order to set the call-to-action button:
// 1. User must have been authenticated with scopes including
//    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login".
// 2. |setURLToShare:| must also be called.
```

Sorry for the confusion, we will update the docs to make the requirement clear. Thanks!

Comment: How is this possible? I could use interactive post the day before the problem. Even I can post screen shots of the posts, if you just want to look at.

Comment: Once I start having this problem, `description` is not posted , whereas `title` and `thumbnailURL` are posted.

Comment: There was a bug on the iOS framework and it was not notifying the error, and that has been fixed now.

Comment: still I have a problem of `description` not getting posted. Do I need to update anything? I implemented code for this just a week back. I am using latest Google+ iOS sdk.